# No periodic tasks in django admin

Tags: python, django, celery

I use Celery 3.1.17 and Python 2.7 for my project. And I have installed **django-celery**.

In **celery.py** I use:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=datetime.timedelta(minutes=1))
def debug_task():
    print '123'
    return 'lol'
```

So, I go in admin, I see worker in *Workers*, but it is not any periodic tasks in *Periodic tasks*.

My code works and in console I see:

```
Task app.celery.debug_task[a82425bb-400e-477e-9a6b-1f2e68f30713] succeeded in 0.00270485699912s: 'lol'
```

Why I can't see periodic  tasks in admin? How to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-admin/0.1

Comment: I think, that task must be displayed in admin automatically